# Install chrome extension with Params

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to have a chrome extension that will have some features customized during the installation for instance I want to define a different background color with a URL parameter

Webstoreurl/my extension?color=black
 webstoreurl/myextension/Color=red

Is that possible ?

Answer (score -1):

No. Not by url, the chrome store sets that. Thinking of what on earth you might use that for (given that even if you could add a parameter, everyone would get the same parameter).

If you wanted to change for black on Monday and red on Tuesday, you could have the extension call home (contact your server) where it picks up initial settings.

Comment: Everyone will not get the same parameter,  that's the point, I want to customize it for different users.

Comment: I guessed, my answer is still correct afaik. It answers your question and suggests an alternative.